# Synchronized AD group won't appear in SharePoint site

Tags: active-directory, groups, profile-sync, synchronisation, domain

I wan't to add three users who are on a new AD on another Domain Name that the one I use habitually, on my test server there no problemes and after I add a connection to the new domain and I launch a complete user profile synchronization, I can add the new users in SharePoint Group from a site.

But on my release server, I add a connection and launch a user profile synchronization and there are no matters ( I can see in the logs there are three profile added) but when I searched new users to add in a sharepoint site, I didn't find anything...

Maybe you have a solution ?
Thank you

PS: sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is an AD problem. We have here two SharePoint installations, one for productive usage and one for testing. We also have two AD and two Exchange server.
Test-AD has a group called SharePoint Admins Universal Group Properties and contains the user folder from the one and the other AD.
This is to get known of the common users of productive SharePoint to test environment.

This is what I can tell you my admin told me and I know that it works, because I can add all common users inside my test Sites.

But I'm not sure if there should be another way because not all time you have access to AD, only to SharePoint.

Comment: Thank you, it's OK there was an authorization missing on the new AD for this SharePoint server exclusively !